# Manually reporting a crash to Android Vitals

Tags: android, error-handling, crash-reports, android-vitals

Is it possible to manually report a crash or error to the Android Vitals statistics. As for now I've been able to close my application nicely with an error message for the user, where it used to crash.

However, I would still like to have these "soft" crashes reported to Android Vitals, is this possible?

(Note that the app I'm developing is a pure NDK/C++ application)

Comment: I'd love to know how you manage to close your app nicely when there's a crash in the C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in an answer to [Android vitals and exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51830422/android-vitals-and-exception-handling) the approach from https://proandroiddev.com/hide-your-crashes-gracefully-and-still-report-them-9b1c85b25875 might be a partial solution.

I don't know enough about how and when crashes are reported (i.e. sent from the Android device to Google) to have confidence the approach will work for you. Do please post your progress here.